# Shortcut for "Commit and Push" option of Android Studio "Code Analysis dialog"

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I try to reduce use of mouse and hence look for / set shortcut keys for common functions. This one has been challenging.

Often dialog like this (for android studio 4.2-, this comes as banner from top) when I try to commit. I know ideal would be to fix those warnings but what if I really want to ignore those warnings. I want to execute "Commit and Push" just by using keyboard. I tried with different key combinations (like cmd+option+c/i/p), tab key but focus remains on "Review". (AS 4.2- is even worst, I can change focus with tab but as soon as I hit "Enter" it just execute "Review).

I can use some experts' advice. How can I execute "Commit and Push" from this dialog only with keyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This popup is a new macOS native alert.

To make to turn on the keyboard navigation in alerts, please, go to macOS System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts and check the Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls option. After enabling it, you will be able to navigate in alerts with Tab/Shift+Tab and once you are on "Commit and push" press Spacebar to confirm.

Comment: This works to change focus but still AS executes "Review" instead of "Commit" action. As captured in this screen recoding: https://youtu.be/ucHj5UTM4QU

Comment: @HBB20 could you please clarify whether you press Enter or Space once the focus is on "Commit and push"?

Comment: Oh you are right.. I should have read last line.. Thanks 